# how to host asp.net website using sql data base

Tags: asp.net

please suggest me how to host asp.net website using sql data base. i published sql.mdf file. is it (sql.mdf) possible to place in app_data folder?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. If you want to use your database from withing the ASP.NET application, put the MDF file in App_Data and modify the connection string in web.config to point to that file. Otherwise, please elaborate.

Answer (score 2):

You need SQL Server to host the database.

Just putting the .mdf file in the app_data folder will not allow you to access the data in it.

In your website you will need to use [ado.net](http://www.ado.net/), [Linq to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx) or another data access layer to connect to the SQL server.

You should be able to use [SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/), if cost is an issue.